# Magento 2 : Disable RequireJS (and all JavaScript)

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, requirejs

Is there a way to disable RequireJS completely in Magento 2? I want to build a theme from scratch and I do not want to include any of JavaScript that Magento automatically includes, Including RequireJS.

There is a documented way of disabling any Magento 2 JS: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#disable_default_js (though I had little success with that so far), but this still would not disable the integration of RequireJS.

Comment: Your work will be amazing. It may take 1 - 2 years :)

Comment: Usually this question is not asked too often on stackexchange, let me break with this tradition though: _Why?_

Comment: We do not require most of the functionality provided by Magento for our theme. However, in the end we will probably still need some JavaScript functionality from modules (third party or otherwise), so I guess disabling the RequireJS mechanic of Magento 2 won't be the way to go anyway ;)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not really. It would be far too difficult anyway ;)